# Different results using f@expr and expr // f in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was playing around with the `Prefix` and `Postfix` operators (`@` and `//` respectively) and I ran into the following issue.

Given the following code, they evaluate in the same exact way:

```
Hold[MatrixPlot@Sort@data] // FullForm
(* Hold[MatrixPlot[Sort[data]]] *)

Hold[data // Sort // MatrixPlot] // FullForm
(* Hold[MatrixPlot[Sort[data]]] *)
```

However, given the following expressions, I get different results:

```
FunctionExpand@Abs'[0]
(* Abs'[0] *)

Abs'[0] // FunctionExpand
(* 0 *)
```

I'm not quite sure really why this is. In dozens of other snippets of code I've had, `f@expr`, `expr // f`, and `f[expr]` all evaluate to the same result. Why does this one particular case give this result?

Comment: This link is possibly relevant: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node174.html, where I discuss similar precedence - related issues. Using `FullForm` on original expression often helps.

Comment: @Leonid `FullForm` is a much better way to see what's happening than what I suggested; I added this to my answer, hope you don't mind

Comment: @acl Great! I was typing the answer using it when your came out, so I discarded mine, voted for yours and left the link. It's good to have both approaches listed.

Comment: The undocumented{?} function `Precedence`  gives the following:  `Precedence[#] & /@ {Prefix, Postfix, Infix}` -> {640., 70., 630.}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a precedence issue. @ has higher precedence than //. To see what is going on, place the cursor on `FunctionExpand` in both cases, then either cmd+. (on OS X) or ctrl+. on anything else, and you end up selecting things by precedence.

Another way to see it is to use `Trace`:

```
FunctionExpand@Abs'[0] // Trace
(*
-> {{{FunctionExpand[Abs],Abs},Abs^\[Prime]},(Abs^\[Prime])[0]}
*)
```

while

```
Abs'[0] // FunctionExpand//Trace
(*
-> {FunctionExpand[(Abs^\[Prime])[0]],0}
*)
```

In particular, notice how in the first case mma first evaluates `FunctionExpand[Abs]`, obtaining `Abs`, then continuing. This is precisely due to how strongly `@` binds as compared to `//`.

EDIT: Inspired by @Leonid's comment, this is also informative:

```
Hold[FunctionExpand@Abs'[0]] // FullForm
Hold[Abs'[0] // FunctionExpand] // FullForm
(*
-> Hold[Derivative[1][FunctionExpand[Abs]][0]]
   Hold[FunctionExpand[Derivative[1][Abs][0]]]
*)
```

which is a much better demonstration of what is going on.